# how can we compare two list?

Tags: java

I have 2 lists of classes namely StuPersonal of Database1,StuPersonal of Database2 of  different size.

```
 public List<StuPersonal> stpers(){

      int size=0;

   Session s=getmSession();
   Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();

  List<StuPersonal> splM=new ArrayList();

   Query q=s.createQuery("from StuPersonal"); 

   splM=q.list();

    tx.commit();
    s.close();

    return splM;

  }

 public List<StuPersonal> stpersl(){

      int size=0;
      List<StuPersonal> splL=new ArrayList();


   Session s=getlSession();
   Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();

   List<StuPersonal> spl=new ArrayList();

   Query q=s.createQuery("from StuPersonal");

    splL=q.list();


  tx.commit();
  s.close();

    return splL;

  }
```

Now i have to compare both the lists and need to take the items which are not in the presented in the second list.i.e some objects are not in the class 2 list so it needs to be stored. I have written this code which is not working properly. Please advice.

```
for(StuPersonal cl:sp)

{
for(StuPersonal cl2:sp2)
        {

           if(cl.getid().equals(cl2.getid()))
            {
                //i++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
            fun.updatelist(cl.getid());
            break;
            }

        }        
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with MySQL or Hibernate. Please don't add unrelated tags to your questions.

Comment: And please post code that at least compiles.

Answer (score 2):

You are Checking the ID of List object not the `Class_1` Object  Id

```
 if(cl.getid() == cl2.getid())
            {
                //i++;
                break;
            } else
        {
        fun.updatelist(cl2.getid());
        break;
        }
```

And you are using equals method, considering id as long not `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not helping yourself by choosing awful names for your variables and methods, not respecting the standard naming conventions, and not correctly indenting your code.

Anyway, you should try to write short methods that do one thing only, and that represent the steps in your task. Your task is to produce a list of objects that are present in list1 but are not in present in list 2. And "being present" here means "an object with the same ID exists in the list".

So start by writing a method `isPresent()`:

```
/**
 * Returns true if an object with the same ID as the ID of the given object is
 * present in the given list
 */
private boolean isPresent(StuPersonal object, List<StuPersonal> list) {
    for (StuPersonal candidate : list) {
        if (candidate.getId().equals(object.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can use this method in your algorithm:

```
// start with an empty list
List<StuPersonal result = new ArrayList<>();

// add every element of list1 unless it's present in list2
for (StuPersonal s : list1) {
    if (!isPresent(s, list2)) {
        result.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, its working...I have modified code according to my class and I'll improve on what you said above. Thank you so much for your guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with String for your scenario.

```
    List<String> firstList = Arrays.asList("obj1", "obj2", "obj3");
    List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList("obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4", "obj5");
    List<String> storedList = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (String obj2 : secondList) {
       if (!firstList.contains(obj2)) {
           storedList.add(obj2);
       }
    }
```